# How to limit angles in (-180,180) range just like Unity3D inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get *rotation* of **Camera** *gameobject* attached to **Char** *gameobject*

EDIT: Char rotation, pos, scale is 0,0,0

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have following code: (Script is on the **Char** *gameobject*)

```
Transform cameraT = transform.Find("Camera").transform;
print(cameraT.localEulerAngles);
```

The problem is that in inspector it shows: 
[image: transform ss]

but in debug console:

[image]

I want to get rotation from inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-45` and `315` are same rotations. Inspector just shows it differently.

> I want to get rotation from inspector

use

```
angle %=360;
angle= angle>180 ? angle-360 : angle;
```

to limit it from `-180` to `180` that's what inspector displays.

Hope this helps

Comment: nvm typed 180 degress

Comment: result isnt correct (when inspector x rotation is bigger than 0 it prints -360 and bigger values

Comment: This code does not provide the requested functionality by OP. When angle is below -180 degrees it will display - X instead of +X; So the range of this method is -360 : 180;

Answer (score 0):

That`s because you look at Global or Local Camera position.

Check it near the Left-Top corner, near the "Pivot" button

Comment: EDIT: Char rotation, pos, scale is 0,0,0

Comment: @MarcinNowak 
print(cameraT.localEulerAngles);
you printing Euler angles (Radians?), but in inspector shown degrees

Comment: then how to get degress. Tried .rotation, .localRotation but its an Quaternion

Comment: @RichardTyshchenko inspector euler angles ARE in degrees. Inspector displays it differently. It doesn't have anything to do with radians

Comment: @MarcinNowak check my answer

Comment: @MarcinNowak
localRotation
or localRotation.x, localRotation.y, localRotation.z

Comment: Yea, Umair's answer is true

Comment: Umairs answer is true (typed 180 instead of 360)

Comment: it isnt again (when inspector x rotation is bigger than 0 it prints -360 and bigger values

Answer (score 0):

To provide a correct answer that was requested by OP which would provide values between (-180, 180] we need to slightly modify the code provided by Umari M

```
float RoundAngle(float angle)
{
    angle %= 360;
    return  angle > 180 ? angle - 360 : angle < -180 ? angle + 360 : angle;
}
```

Readable version with comments

```
float RoundAngle2(float angle)
{
    // Make sure that we get value between (-360, 360], we cannot use here module of 180 and call it a day, because we would get wrong values
    angle %= 360;
    if (angle > 180)
    {
        // If we get number above 180 we need to move the value around to get negative between (-180, 0]
        return angle - 360;
    }
    else if (angle < -180)
    {
        // If we get a number below -180 we need to move the value around to get positive between (0, 180]
        return angle + 360;
    }
    else
    {
        // We are between (-180, 180) so we just return the value
        return angle;
    }
}
```